# How do I write the whole csv file into a dictionary using for loops

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read a csv file and write it into a dictionary. Col 1 would be my key and col 2 would be the item I am writing. It seems to work however, when I print the dictionary only the last row appears in the dictionary.

```
def compare_csv(fileone, filetwo):
    dict1 = {}
    with open(fileone, 'r') as dataset1:
        for line in csv.DictReader(dataset1):
            dict1.update(line)
    print(dict1)
```

Here is what my csv file looks like

```
id,num
1,123
2,23,2,3
3,41,78
```

This is what I get when I print the dictionary

```
`{'id': '3', 'num': '41, 78'}`
```

What I want instead is

```
{'id': 'num', '1': '123', '2': '23, 2, 3', '3': '41, 78'}
```

I'm not sure exactly why that happens because when I use my for loop doesn't that iterate each row so that the DictReader reads col1 as the key and col2 as the item? Also, side question would this be the most efficient way to search and compare for something. For example, I am iterating through all my dictionary key (id) and seeing if the items match from another list. So for example, if I am on key 2, I am checking another list to see if the number 23, 2 and 3 are all on that list. I've thought about using panda but I can't install it on the system here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` function updates a key in a dictionary.

Printing the lines that result from `csv.DictReader` shows:

```
{'id': '1', 'num': '123'}
{'id': '2', 'num': '23', None: ['2', '3']}
{'id': '3', 'num': '41', None: ['78']}
```

What is happening is that you read and write the two dict indices `id` and `num`, so after always overwriting them, they at the end are the values of the last line.

What you can for example is to split the line and write the values as you need.

```
with open(fileone, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
   key = line.split(",")[0]
   value = ", ".join(line.split(",")[1:])
   dict1[key] = value
```

Embedded into the full code, it can look like this.

```
def compare_csv(fileone, filetwo):
    dict1 = {}
    with open(fileone, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        key = line.split(",")[0]
        value = ", ".join(line.split(",")[1:])
        dict1[key] = value

    return dict1

print(compare_csv('./test.csv', './test.csv'))
```

The above sample produces the intended output:

```
{'id': 'num', '1': '123', '2': '23, 2, 3', '3': '41, 78'}
```

Comment: I believe this what I am looking for but I'm getting a syntax error the line "dict1[key] = value"

Comment: I missed a `)` in the line above, sorry for that. Edited the answer.